# How to use moment.js properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I have made a sample page which contains this:

```js
var date = '2015-04-03';
var formate = 'LLLL';
var result = moment(date).format(format);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

And as you can see I have included the **moment.js** file in order to retrieve data from it and displaying a valid date in the browser. (Here is the link to moment.js that I have inlcuded: [link](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js))

But I don't know why it does not work at all! Can u guys help how to use moment.js in proper way ?! Thanks...

Comment: Is it because you initialize `formate` but try to use `format`?

Comment: Replace formate with format

Comment: Nice catch ,but it doesn't work either ! No error & No result...

Comment: Please look at your console. It is much faster than asking SO.

Comment: It's pretty much impossible that this code would not print anything in the console, not even an error message, unless the browser is seriously broken. Are you sure you have the console open?

Comment: You should in particular check your network tab : is moment.js properly loaded? For example, if you're trying this out in local and accessing the page through a `file://` url, moment.js won't be available even if the file is present in the same directory as your html page.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote "format**e**" instead of "format".

Appart from this, you code works fine.

```js
var date = '2015-04-03';
var format = 'LLLL';
var result = moment(date).format(format);
document.write(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```